I accidently deleted Bluetooth Support Service, how do I get it back?
Bluetooth Support Service is an integral service for bluetooth functionality and somehow I ended up accidently deleting or breaking it. I have a bluetooth adapter and have tried reinstalling, rebooting and updating but cannot pair any bluetooth devices.
The main reason is the missing service and I am not sure how to reinstall it without reinstalling Windows.
I can turn On/Off the adapter but that still doesn't allow devices to be paired. It was through various troubleshooting efforts to remove ghost devices that were failing to be removed that I may have gone overboard.
It turns out I needed to re-enable the motherboard bluetooth in order to remove the ghost devices paired with that device, then re-disable it. I have a new adapter (newer bluetooth version) that was working but I wanted to remove the ghost devices and now nothing bluetooth works.
The Windows Bluetooth troubleshooter is useless and just checks to make sure I see a On/Off toggle. There are no windows updates (optional or otherwise) that are available.

I would perform an in-place upgrade to the same version of Windows 11 you are running. You don't mention how you uninstalled the service so it's difficult to tell you how to reinstall it.

Yeah you are probably correct. Are there specific steps to avoid data loss?
The removal was from a command that I believe literally deleted the service. Given there's a way to delete it, I figured there was a way to re-add it. (sc delete bthserv)

That info should have been in the question body. It is not too late to add it. Use the EDIT button to do this. An in-place upgrade of Windows should not delete any user data. Backups are always the best way to avoid any data loss though, so take a backup first.


Make a Bootable Windows 11 installer USB with Rufus
Start the setup from within Windows 11
Install on top of existing Windows 11 by keeping files+data
System reboots and restores missing service(s)


Uninstall device from device manager then restart Bluetooth service. Right-click "Bluetooth Support Service." Choose Automatic. Install the Bluetooth device drivers from the manufacturer's website, if any.

There is no "Bluetooth Support Service" to restart. I have already attempted removing all bluetooth components in Device Manager and it made no improvement.
